# passing php variable to jquery deletes variable contents

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to send a variable from my php script to my jquery. My php script helps upload a file and echos the file's contents. It is the contents of the txt file that I am trying to pass to my jquery. The echo statement in the final line of the php script correctly echos the contents of the variable. However, passing this to jquery, it acts as if the variable is empty.

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');

foreach($_FILES as $file) {
    $n = $file['name'];
    $s = $file['size'];
    $t = $file["tmp_name"];
    $GLOBALS['content'] = file_get_contents($t);

    if (is_array($n)) {
        $c = count($n);
        for ($i=0; $i < $c; $i++) {
            //echo "<br>uploaded: " . $n[$i] . " (" . $s[$i] . " bytes)";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "<br>uploaded: $n ($s bytes)";
    }
}
echo $GLOBALS['content'];

?>
```

If I echo something different. Such as `echo "dog"`, dog is correctly sent to the jquery.

and the jquery. The testform is a separate form from when I upload the file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#testform').submit(function () {
        $.get("http://www.econreader.netau.net/upload.php", function(data) {
            $element = data;
            $("p").text(data);
            $('body').append($element);

        }); 
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: _“It acts as if”_ is not what I would call an error description … so what you done so far to acutally _debug_ this?

Comment: File uploads can't be submitted using `$.get()`.

Comment: Does the file get uploaded? I don't think so. You intercept the submitting of the form and make a simple GET request to the PHP file, ignoring the form

Comment: you aren't specifying any files to upload.

Comment: If you want to upload files using AJAX, try using the Jquery Forms plugin http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload

Comment: @Barmar: I am actually using this exact JQuery Form Plugin. I'm trying to get the contents of the file that I'm uploading and send it to my query. I found the documentation to be lacking, however.

Comment: @Kevin B: The file is being uploaded with a JQuery Form Plugin, and PHP echo statement outputs the file contents so I'm pretty sure the file is being uploaded.

Comment: @JoeDanger the $.get isn't doing it. If something else is, great, but i don't see any indication of that from your code.

Comment: If I echo something different. Such as `echo "dog";`, dog is correctly sent to the jquery. So I think its a problem with the variable type maybe?

Comment: `$GLOBALS['content']` is empty, correct?

Comment: The problem is that there's nothing in `$_FILES` when you use `$.get`, so you're never setting `$_GLOBALS['content']` to anything.

Comment: You should be doing what you want in the callback from `$.ajaxForm()`